# convergence of $\sqrt{-e-e²+e^3+\frac{1}{-e-e²+e^3}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-e-e²+e^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{-e-e²+e^3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{-e-e²+e^3}}+\cdots }$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

I want to check convergence of sequence which is related to exponential function i have come up with this sequence such that I run some computations in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt((-e%C2%B2%2Be%5E3-e%2B1%2F(-e%C2%B2%2Be%5E3-e)-sqrt(1%2F(-e%C2%B2%2Be%5E3-e))%2B(1%2F(-e%C2%B2%2Be%5E3-e)%5E(1%2F3)-(1%2F(-e%C2%B2%2Be%5E3-e)%5E(1%2F5)%2B(1%2F(-e%C2%B2%2Be%5E3-e)%5E(1%2F7))))))) it's seems that is convergent , but my Goal is to know if the bellow sum could be an integer number .

$S=\sqrt{-e-e²+e^3+\frac{1}{-e-e²+e^3}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-e-e²+e^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{-e-e²+e^3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{-e-e²+e^3}}+\cdots }$

?

Comment: I honestly fail to see the pattern here

Comment: When you put it in Wolfram alpha, does it look like it converges to an integer?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to write the sequence defined by

$$S^2:=C+\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^{k+1} C^{-1/k}$$

for $C:=-e-e^2+e^3$. The series doesnt converge because the inner sequence $(C^{-1/k})_{k\in\Bbb N_{>0}}$ doesnt converge to zero.

Comment: It matters not! This series converges to 3.2241 according to computational simulations....

Comment: Where is the $k=4$ term in the question? (Nice try though.)

Comment: @Did, you are right, then there's no pattern apparently, I hope the OP clarifies that